# Inline tag editor delay enabling

Tags: bug, inline-tag-editor

The inline tag editor for questions should have the `disabled` attribute while the pillbox is loading. There are times where I edit and the browser doesn't catch up to my typing.

1. Click the button for the tags `[foo] [bar]`
2. I start typing which is a regular `input type="text"` at that time: `foo bar`. It becomes  `newtextfoo bar` (notice the space, I'm trying to add the `newtext` tag.
3. The pill box appears breaking the `foo` tag: `[newtextfoo] [bar]`

Can we fix that or force the focus to the end of the `input type="text"`?

[image]

Comment: I have reproduced this many times, although I usually blamed my own impatience and never took the time to draft a bug report. The animated GIF is very helpful here, I think. It would be nice to look into solutions for fixing this. I usually use Chromium-based browsers, so that's probably where I've reproduced this. I also use Firefox on some computers, but I can't remember if I have reproduced it there or not.

Comment: I can reproduce this on Firefox. I've never been that impatient, though, and have always waited for the editor to appear. (Probably because I'm expecting to have to click in the thing first before I can type in it.)